# How do I get the text size and behaviour in IE to match my other browsers using only HTML/CSS/SVG?

Tags: html, css

I want a large header that resizes with the window. The following code does what I want in Windows 10 Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Opera (current versions), but not in Internet Explorer.

```html
<doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <style>
    .bigh {
      font-size: 63px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="headline" fill="transparent" d="M50 50 l 400 0"/>
    <!--path id="headline" fill="transparent" d="M80 100 A 180 60, 0, 0, 1, 420 100"/-->
     <text width="500" text-anchor="middle" fill="red">
     <textPath class="bigh" xlink:href="#headline" startOffset="50%" spacing = "auto">
       BIG HEADER
     </text>
    </svg>
  </body>

  </html>
```

In IE the text is much smaller than the oher browsers.

[image: Opera]

[image: IE]

How do I get IE to display the text at the same size as the rest and still resize with the window? I don't mind serving separate code, I just don't know what to serve.

Edit: Kosh Very's answer sorts out the size problem. IE still differs from the other browsers (see image below) but that should be easier to fix.
[image]

Comment: I think IE11 requires that SVG elements are styled using attributes, not using CSS. So your CSS `font-size` rule won't apply. Can you try adding the style rule inline? `<text font-size="63"...>`

Comment: I tried it. No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `viewBox="0 0 500 110"` would help:

```html
<doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <style>
    .bigh {
      font-size: 63px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 110">
<path id="headline" fill="transparent" d="M80 100 A 180 60, 0, 0, 1, 420 100"/>
<text width="500" text-anchor="middle" fill="red">
 <textPath class="bigh" xlink:href="#headline" startOffset="50%" spacing = "auto">
   BIG HEADER
 </text>
</svg>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm actually trying to produce a curved header as in the commented out path I've inserted. Same problem occurs.

Comment: Many thanks. That's solved the main puzzle. Text comes out half way down in IE (see edit to query) but hopefully sortable with conditional CSS.

Comment: @MartinRattigan, my snippet runs in IE without extra space. Probably you have other elements and styles which may cause the spacing?

Comment: Sorry. Only just saw that. As you say, if you specify the required header size in vw and vh units there are no problems.